# How to use INDIRECT in Excel for quoting sheet name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

[image]

For example, I have sheets

```
Level 3 Grade G
Level 4 Grade F
Level 5 Grade E
Level 6 Grade D
Level 7 Grade C
Level 8 Grade B
```

I wish to use cell `F2` for the these names and make references. For example, when `F2` is `Level 3 Grade G`,

I wish to have

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Level 3 Grade G'!$A$1:$B$30,2)
```

and when `F2` is `Level 4 Grade F`,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Level 4 Grade F'!$A$1:$B$30,2)
```

and when `F2` is `Level 5 Grade E`,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Level 5 Grade E'!$A$1:$B$30,2)
```

I have tried something like

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Indirect(F2)!$A$1:$B$30,2)
```

which did not seem to work.

As you can see from below, in `B2` I have used the exact formula,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Level 3 Grade G'!$A$1:$B$30,2)
```

How can I make it automatically take `F1` as the sheetname?

Comment: Please [Edit], and share some sample data,, since few are confusing,,, like what is in `A2` to match into sheets,, and what you are trying to retrieve!!

Comment: Try =VLOOKUP(A2,Indirect(F2&"!$A$1:$B$30"),2)

Comment: @RajeshS , what I am trying to get, is to be able to use the `value` in `F2` as `sheetname` refereneces in the `vlookup` function.

Comment: @RajeshS I have added a picture, hopefully should make it clearer. At the moment, I used the sheetname as it is. But I want to be able to use the cell value from `F1` as the names.

Comment: @CasperYC,, but your formula does not match with the data just now you have shared with us ,, what I'm realizing that you want to lookup value across sheets from same data range,, if yes please [edit] your post & add such line and confirm through comments also!

Comment: @RajeshS Yes, that's what `for example` mean. EXAMPLES are examples. The only difference is what the cell I wish to quote, `F2` instead of `F1`. Other things are not of any importance.

Comment: @RajeshS As long as I can get `B2` to use the correct formula, the rest is a mouse drag...and automatically filled by Excel. Only problem here is, how to quote `F1` as sheetname?

Comment: Ok @CasperYC,, after few minutes check my post .

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks. Look forward to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Sheet  2` *(note the spaces in the sheetname)* is like:

[image]

then in another sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'" & F1 & "'!$A$1:$B$30"),2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

*What exactly you are trying is, to get values from multiple sheets, using lookup method from identical data range, for particular match with data in `A2`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- In `Sheet 4`, enter sheet name, as shown in range `G150:G152`.
- Assign header `Sheet List`, or any of your choice.
- Select `G149:G152`, and from **F**ormula TAB, Name Manager section, hit **C**reate from selection and check **T**op Row.
- Enter this formula in cell `J149` and fill down.

  ```
  =VLOOKUP(I149,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(Sheet_List,MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&Sheet_List&"'!$G$141:$H$144"),I149)>0),0))&"'!$G$141:$H$144"),2,FALSE)
  ```

*You may use this one too.*

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I149, Sheet1!$G$141:$H$144, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I149, Sheet2!$G$141:$H$144, 2, FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I149, Sheet3!$G$141:$H$144, 2, FALSE),"Not found")))
```

**N.B.**

- *`Sheet_List`* is Named Range, reads match data from Sheet 1 to 3 in `G141:H144`.
- To show data from three sheets, since I need to accommodate data in one screen, that's why you find them in different columns, **otherwise should have in identical data range.**
- *You may alter Sheet name as well cell references in the formula as needed.*